# React and Redux: Getting is not defined no-undef error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I do not know why I keep getting the following error: 'isAuthenticated' is not defined  no-undef. I grabbed it from mapStateToProps and then I called it within my switch tag. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

//App.js file

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        store.dispatch(loadUser());
    }, []);
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                        {!isAuthenticated ? <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} /> : <ProtectedRoute exact path="/userfeed" component={UserFeed} />}

                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </Provider>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: You're mixing functional and class component syntax. Functional components don't have a render function, they *are* the render function. You just return the JSX

Comment: Sorry I am still learning. Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `isAuthenticated` will be pass as the component props, you need to get it from the component props and you have to define the provider in the parent component.

Try the below code.

```
const App = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        store.dispatch(loadUser());
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                    {!isAuthenticated ? <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} /> : <ProtectedRoute exact path="/userfeed" component={UserFeed} />}
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './App'
import store from './store'
ReactDOM.render(
    // Render a `<Provider>` around the entire `<App>`,
    // and pass the Redux store to as a prop
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

For details please read the guide in official doc [here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-5-ui-react).

Comment: I got the following error: Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

Comment: @tim_woods the provider is **inside** your App component, so you won't be able to connect the App component itself. Anything that you're connecting needs to be rendered as a child of the provider

Comment: @Jayce444 thank you for your reply. I updated my code above by adding render() as you had suggested but I got the following error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";". The error is pointing to the line where its render()

Comment: Render is not used in functional component, he means to say that the App component should be a child of the provider component.

Comment: use the provider in the parent component.

Comment: Sorry I am still learning. Can you show me in the code you provided above?

Comment: I have added the code for index.js, please adjust the store path accordingly